# Geting html in a column value. how to remove it

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am having this code to load data from content list to grid view.

```
private void Data_load()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string currentName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='Person or Group'>" + currentName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spdev-6/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lists = web.GetList("Lists/Advertisements");

                SPListItemCollection items = lists.GetItems(query);
                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    dt = items.GetDataTable();

                }
                else
                    lbldata.Text = "No data to show";



                GridViewD.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewD.DataBind();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Advertisement"] = dt;


            }
        }
```

Now the problem is i am having grid-view in following way.

I have to remove the div and Html from this column. I just want the description without HTML div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following solution

Disable the HTML render in the wanted column:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyColumn" HtmlEncode="false" />
```